# Java array question

Tags: java, arrays, search

Sorry, silly question here, I have googled it but anything I search for seems to be returning methods of using binary search etc., but what I need is actually much simpler.

I have an array of languages. I am creating a scanner, asking for input. Trying to make it so that if the language input by the user isn't in the array, it displays an error and asks again. Should be simple, I have just drawn a blank.

Can anyone help please ? Here is what I have so far !

```
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      language = scan.next();
      while( language NOT IN ARRAY languages) {
       System.out.print("error!");
       language = scan.next();
     }
```

Comment: That is not even valid Java code...

Comment: So the issue is trying determine whether a value is in an array already, i.e. searching for a specific value in an array?

Comment: I realise this, its psuedo code. Point out where I said it was valid code ?

Comment: Bert F - Yes, that is it ! :) I have a string, which the user inputs, I then search the array to see if it is contained within it.

Comment: Is this homework? Do you need to use only array operations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand your question better now.  You should use a [`Set`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) for sure.  But you will want to use the `contains()` method of the set to check if the language exists.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
language = scan.next();
while(!set.contains(language)) {
    System.out.print("error!");
    language = scan.next();
}
```

*Old answer, still relevant info though:*
What yo want to use is a [`Set`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) collection type. A set does not allow duplicate entries.
From the Javadocs:

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements.

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
// will not add another entry if set contains language already
set.add(language);
```

Also, if you want to know if the value was rejected or not, you can use the return type of the add() method. It returns true if the item did not exist, and false otherwise.

Comment: strange way to use set; why not just use the contains() method?   Also this way he will accumulate all the inputs in the set which is not what he wants.

Comment: This is almost a complete answer. I would also point out the contains( "xyz" ) api on the Set class, which can be used to drive that loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
public static boolean contains(String language, String[] lang_array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lang_array.length; i++) {
        if (lang_array[i].equals(language))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] lang_array = {"Java", "Python", "Ruby"};
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String language = scan.next();
    while(!contains(language, lang_array)) {
        System.out.print("error!");
        language = scan.next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this is you really need to use an array:

```
   Arrays.sort(languages);
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   language = scan.next();
   while( Arrays.binarySearch(languages, language) < 0) {
    System.out.print("error!");
    language = scan.next();
   }
```

Comment: Would that be  while( !Arrays.binarySearch(languages, language) < 0 ) ? Since you can't use a not on an int and that method returns int ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do:

Either iterate through the array and compare the contents on each element to what you're trying to see if it's there every time you add a language.

OR

Use a LinkedList or some other kind of Java Structure that has a `.contains()` method, this will, in a way, do something similar to what I mentioned for the Array.